# Want to select below mention details in one single query

Tags: sql

My first EMPLOYEE Table contains following fields:

id,employee_Name,city_code

FK-->EMPLOYEE(city_code) reference CITY(id)

second table CITY contains following fields:

id,city_name,state_code

FK-->CITY(state_code) reference STATE(id)

third table STATE contains:

id,state_name

I want to SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE but instead of city_code FROM EMPLOYEE i want particular city_name FROM CITY and state_name from STATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `JOIN` :

```
select e.id, e.employee_Name, c.city_name, s.state_name
from employee e
inner join city c on c.id = e.city_code
inner join state s on s.id = c.state_code
```

Comment: I have eited my question @Yogesh Sharma can u please tell me further solution

Comment: @BZT. . . Do join again with state table